# Retrieving thread id from a thread object before starting the thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

Is there any way to receive a thread id from a thread object before actually starting the thread?
For example:

```
 t = threading.Thread(
                name=...
                target=...
                args=...
)

# I want the id here

t.start()
```

Is that possible or is there any other workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says 'no': 
ident

    The ‘thread identifier’ of this thread or None if the thread has not been started. This is a nonzero integer. See the get_ident() function. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created. The identifier is available even after the thread has exited.` but you can work around this by e.g. making the thread function immediately wait on a semaphore which your code that starts the thread only hits once it's got the ident? But this sounds like an X-Y problem; what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Can you clarify why you need this? Thread identifiers are dynamically set when the underlying thread (not its representing object) is actually started. Trying to guess the ID before the thread is started opens you to various race conditions, in that *any* other thread starting inbetween invalidates your guess. Note that Python itself uses threads for various things behind the scenes, so even if you do not use additional threads explicitly there might still *be* additional threads outside of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, the documentation states clearly that `ident` (and `native_id`) is None before the thread has started. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=ident#threading.Thread.ident

Here's a way you can get the `ident` or `native_id` before the thread has done anything useful, using a semaphore which the main code acquires before starting the thread, and releases once main is ready for the thread to continue.

```
import threading
import time

def threadfunc(word1,word2):
    global s
    print( f"Thread Started" )
    print( f"Thread Acquiring sempahore" )
    s.acquire()
    print( f"Thread Acquired sempahore" )
    print( f"{word1}, {word2}" )
    # do something useful ....
    time.sleep(0.1)
    # wrap-up
    print( f"Thread Releasing sempahore" )
    s.release()
    print( f"Thread Released sempahore" )
    print( "Thread Finished" )

s = threading.Semaphore()

print( f"Main Acquiring sempahore" )
s.acquire()
print( f"Main Acquired sempahore" )

t = threading.Thread(
                name='mythread'
                ,target=threadfunc
                ,args=("hello","world")
    )

# I want the id here
id = t.ident

print( f"Thread id before start: {id}" )

print( "Main starting thread" )
t.start()
print( "Main started thread" )

id1 = t.ident

print( f"Thread id after start: {id1}" )

print( f"Main Releasing sempahore" )
s.release()
print( f"Main Released sempahore" )

t.join()
print( "Main Finished" )
```

Result:

```
Main Acquiring sempahore
Main Acquired sempahore
Thread id before start: None
Main starting thread
Thread Started
Main started thread
Thread Acquiring sempahore
Thread id after start: 16932
Main Releasing sempahore
Main Released sempahore
Thread Acquired sempahore
hello, world
Thread Releasing sempahore
Thread Released sempahore
Thread Finished
Main Finished
```

`Semaphore` documentation is here https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=semaphore#threading.Semaphore

Other synchronization methods are available, e.g. `Lock`, `RLock`, conditions, etc, and could easily be used instead of `Sempahore` - all are on the doc link above.

Comment: From reading all the comments, it looks to me that there is no easy way of doing this, and it probably also would be a bad practice. However, if someone is trying to get something similar to this, this comment can help. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not possible. Thread ID's are retrieved using the `native_id` member on a `Thread` object and are only available with a valid value after the thread has been started. From the Python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.native_id):

> The native integral thread ID of this thread. This is a non-negative
> integer, or None if the thread has not been started. See the
> get_native_id() function. This represents the Thread ID (TID) as
> assigned to the thread by the OS (kernel). Its value may be used to
> uniquely identify this particular thread system-wide (until the thread
> terminates, after which the value may be recycled by the OS).